# Can I delete an item of a queryset in python but without deleting that item on the database?

Tags: python, django-queryset

I am creating an app in django, and I have the next problem:

I get a `queryset` using the next command line:

```
queryset = Persons.objects.all()
```

Assume the resulting list is the next one: `['x', 'y', 'z']`

And I want to remove an element `x` of that list, so that the resulting list is: `['y', 'z']`.

I don't want to delete the element `x`. So I cant use the command `item.delete()`.

If my models are:

```
class A(models.Model):
    att1= models.ForeignKey(B)
    att2 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
...

class B(models.Model):
    ident = models.CharField(max_length=128)
...
```

How can I get a queryset of B objects that are related with A and A.att2 value == 'test' ???

Comment: How big is the queryset?

Comment: the queryset could be around 10-15 elements. Does it matter?

Comment: In that case I'd turn it into a list, remove the element, and use the list. Or do you need QuerySet-specific functionality?

Comment: Use the `exclude` function and it will return a queryset without the element you're trying to remove.

Comment: And how can I convert the queryset to list? The exclude function doesn't work in my example, because to know which element must I remove, first I get all the elements in a queryset. I get another queryset with other elements of another model, and then, I want to remove from the first queryset the elements of the second one. In resume, I want to do an INNER JOIN in django, but I don't know how...

Comment: I've just edited my post. Can you help me again, please? That is my real problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need to set related_name:

```
class A(models.Model):
    att1= models.ForeignKey(B, related_name='A_model')
    att2 = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class B(models.Model):
    ident = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

query like this:

```
B.objects.filter(A_model__att2="test")
```

this is my first Answer in stackoverflow hope this will help you

if you don't want to set related_name try:

```
B.A_set.filter(att2="test")
```

Comment: Your don't need to set the related name for cross-models lookups to work.

Comment: @jfernandez178 all this is documented: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
# we usually don't import User directly
# but I just wanted to show how to use exclude
from django.contrib.auth import User
User.objects.all()  # will return all users
# will return exxactly the same queryset
# except that the user with the `admin` username
# will be excluded from the queryset.
User.objects.all().exclude(username='admin')
```

If you have some related fields, such as:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

You can exclude some items where the user has the 'admin' username.
You can use the [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) function.

```
Item.objects.exclude(user__username='admin')
```

Comment: If I have a model of objects A, and another model B which has an attribute of type A, how can I do the next: select B.a from B where B.a NOT IN (Select * from A)???

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create another field

in model something like :

```
class Persons(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

give x a value of "is_active" = False

```
x1 = Persons.objects.get(name='x')
x1.is_active = False
x1.save()
```

now you can filter like this:

```
queryset = Persons.objects.filter(is_active=True)
```